# kentico add new form field via API

Tags: kentico

Hello Kentico experts,

I need to create some new form fields dynamically via Kentico API. I found a solution but it is for Kentico 6 and it is not available for my version (i'm using Kentico 8).

https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-add-a-new-field-to-a-document-type-using-api

Please help !

Thanks,
Duong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```c#
string classname = "classname";
DataClassInfo dci = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(classname);
if (dci != null)
{
    FormInfo fi = new FormInfo(dci.ClassFormDefinition);
    if (fi != null)
    {
        // Field definition
        FormFieldInfo ffi = new FormFieldInfo();
        ffi.Name = "FieldName";
        ffi.AllowEmpty = true;
        ffi.System = false;
        ffi.FieldType = CMS.FormEngine.FormFieldControlTypeEnum.UploadControl;
        ffi.Visible = true;
        ffi.Caption = "Field Caption";
        ffi.Enabled = true;
        // Set whatever properties are relevant to you

        fi.AddFormItem(ffi);

        TableManager tm = new TableManager(null);
        tm.AddTableColumn(dci.ClassTableName, ffi.Name, "uniqueidentifier", true, null);

        dci.ClassXmlSchema = tm.GetXmlSchema(dci.ClassTableName);
        dci.ClassFormDefinition = fi.GetXmlDefinition();

        // Update DataClassInfo object
        DataClassInfoProvider.SetDataClassInfo(dci);

        // Update inherited classes with new field
        FormHelper.UpdateInheritedClasses(dci);

    }
}
```

You can always check the API changes between versions on [Kentico DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-8?page=1).