# Kentico Dynamic Page Type field and updating ClassSearchSettings

Tags: xml, api, indexing, lucene, kentico

I'm running a Kentico 12 MVC site (converted from Kentico 11 MVC), on VIsual Studio 2017, C# 4.61.

I am building a one-off API to convert hundreds of Azure search indexes into new local Smart Search indexes. There's a bit more to this as I also have to update the associated page type.  This involved create a new field, updating another default value, and updating all those search checkboxes for the local index.  I'm nearly there with getting this to work as expected but when I dynamically add my new page type field, update everything successfully, I still can't seem to find my new field within the ClassSearchSettings XML.

I've found another question about creating a new field within a Page Type, and I found that here:  [kentico add new form field via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635926/kentico-add-new-form-field-via-api).  This helped me get the dynamic creation of the field completed.

Here's the low down on what I'm doing, hopefully it will help you, but my real question is further down. *newIndex* is my own instance of a class I've built.

**1) Retrieve indexes here**:

```
  var indexes = SearchIndexInfoProvider.GetSearchIndexes()
          .WhereEquals("IndexSearchServiceName", searchServiceName)
          //.WhereEquals("IndexName", indexName)
          .ToList();
```

**2) Retrieve Page Type items and the associated fields**. I used this block of code, and my parameter, newIndex.PageTypeClassName is retrieved from the previous block, when iterating through the collection.  When on an individual index, use the following code to get the Page Type Class name:

**2a**:

```
newIndex.PageTypeClassName = index.IndexSettings.Items.FirstOrDefault().Value.ClassNames;
```

Then get your Page Type 'stuff' (DataClassInfo, FormInfo, List of FormFieldInfo

**2b**:

```
var dci = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo(newIndex.PageTypeClassName);
var fi = new CMS.FormEngine.FormInfo(dci.ClassFormDefinition);
var pageTypeFields = fi.GetFields(true, true, false);
```

**3) Create and add the new Page Type field**:

```
var newField = new FormFieldInfo
    {
        Name = DataAutomationHelper.FilterAttributeTitle,
        DefaultValue = string.Empty,
        Size = 200,
        Enabled = true,
        AllowEmpty = true,
        System = false,           
        FieldType = FormFieldControlTypeEnum.TextBoxControl,
        DataType = FieldDataType.Text,
        Visible = false, // this is not a visible field, only used for filtering and creation of the LEFT menu items                
    };

    newIndex.FormInfo.AddFormItem(newField, 2);

    var tm = new TableManager(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSConnectionString"].ToString());

    //tm.DropTableColumn(newIndex.CorrectedPageTypeClassName, DataAutomationHelper.FilterAttributeTitle);
    tm.AddTableColumn(newIndex.CorrectedPageTypeClassName, newField.Name, "nvarchar(200)", true, string.Empty);

    // Add new column to database
    newIndex.PageType.ClassXmlSchema = tm.GetXmlSchema(newIndex.CorrectedPageTypeClassName);
    newIndex.PageType.ClassFormDefinition = newIndex.FormInfo.GetXmlDefinition();

    // Update DataClassInfo object
    DataClassInfoProvider.SetDataClassInfo(newIndex.PageType);

    // Update inherited classes with new field
    FormHelper.UpdateInheritedClasses(newIndex.PageType);
```

Yay!  I have a new field within my page type!  I thought that I'd have to get my Page Type again to see the updated fields, but still the *ClassSearchSettings* are the same from before adding the new field.  **Here's the strange thing**:  When I open another browser, view the detail of that Page Type, I can see my new field, and also see it within the list of Search checkboxes too.  Why is this the case?  Does something need to be refreshed? Please let me know what you think, and any help is appreciated!  I can clarify as needed too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I received word from Kentico Support about this, and they recommended that I go this route:

```
var cssi = dci.ClassSearchSettingsInfos;
var ssi = new SearchSettingsInfo()
{
    ID = ffi.Guid,
    Name = ffi.Name
};   ssi.SetFlag(SearchSettings.SEARCHABLE, true);

cssi.Items.Add(ffi.Guid, ssi);
dci.ClassSearchSettings = cssi.GetData();
dci.Update();
```

From one of their support specialists: 
"This involves creating a new *SearchSettingsInfo* for the new field and adding it to *ClassSearchSettingsInfos*. The *SetFlag()* call isn't necessary, but this is to demonstrate that you can configure the field to be Searchable in the code as well."

Hope this helps others!